# Increment (overflow) Short.MAX_VALUE to zero, not Short.MIN_VALUE

Tags: java, integer-overflow, short

I'm working on a 'tabindex' defect in an application that works fine in *Firefox* and *Chrome*, but not *Internet Explorer*.
The 'tabindex' is set through a JSP by a static 'int', which is incremented each time it is used.

```
private static short tabIndex = 1;

sb.append("<select tabindex='").append(tabIndex++) ...
```

*Internet Explorer* has a [maximum 'tabindex'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534654(v=vs.85).aspx) of 32767 (`Short.MAX_VALUE`). So I can change the `int` to a `short`, but after it reaches the maximum, it will tick around to `Short.MIN_VALUE`.

> Objects with a negative tabIndex are omitted from the tabbing order.

So I need it to progress from `Short.MAX_VALUE` to zero.
Obviously, it is trivial to write some code to do this, but I wondered if there is some clever short-hand way that I can increment to a strictly positive number, or some other data type I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that the MSB is always 0 by ANDing the value with `0x7FFF`.

```
short s = 32767;
short s1 = (short)(s & 0x7FFF); // s1 = 32767 (or 0x7FFF)
s++; // s = -32768 (or 0x8000)
short s2 = (short)(s & 0x7FFF); // s2 = 0
```

You might want to extract the incrementation and bitmasking to its own method and just use that inside `append`.

I'm not condoning this code, because it's not very clear and frankly returning from assignment is not something I'd use, but the following would be a very short version:

```
public short incIndex() {
    return tabIndex = (short)(tabIndex+1 & 0x7FFF);
}
```

`...append(incIndex())...`

Comment: Yes, this works (although the compiler won't let me do the bit-twiddling unless I declare the variables as `int` rather than `short`).

Comment: Yeah you need some additional `(short)` casts to prevent the values from being promoted to `int`, but you get the idea.

Comment: Even shorter: `sb.append("<select tabindex='").append((short)(tabIndex++ & 0x7FFF))`

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I avoided that to keep `tabIndex` always within the allowed limits not just masked when used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating our own wrapper type that handles this limitation ?

```
public class ShortValueForTab {

    private short value;       

    public short next() {
        value++;
        if (value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

and in your client code :

```
private static ShortValueForTab tabIndex =  new ShortValueForTab();
...    
sb.append("<select tabindex='").append(tabIndex.next()) ...
```

Comment: That's almost exactly what I have done, but I wondered whether there was  a different way to increment a primitive, or else an existing class either in standard Java or Apache or something.